# array data keep been modifing by not related code

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array and I am tring to take the data that category is 1 and copy it and change category to 2 and push back to the array I have.So I take the data that category is 1 form array and save it into a temp array . And I loop the temp array and change each category of the value to 2 and push back to my original array .It seems quite simple until I found that my original data,the array that suppose to be nothing change but add some more new motified data ,has been change .I've reboot my machine and the server is on aws.Example code is on below .

```
     $tempArr=[];
    $array_origin =
    [
        0=>[
            "id" => 1,
            "category"=>1
            ],

        1=>[
            "id" => 2,
            "category"=>2
            ],
    ];


    foreach ($array_origin as $k => $v) 
    {

      if($v["category"] == 1)
      {
       array_push($tempArr,$v);
      }
    }


    foreach ($tempArr as $k => $v) 
    {
       $v["category"] = 2;
       array_push($array_origin,$v);
    }
```

//it should be

```
/*

Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category] => 2
                )

        )
    */
```

//but the result is

```
        /*
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [category] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category] => 2
                )

        )
        */
```

Comment: I've just tried your code and I can't reproduce the problem, the first element is `[id] => 1, [category] => 1`

Comment: @victor didn't you swap expected and current results?

Comment: @splash58, according to their requirements at the top of the question, they want to copy any item with category 1 and add it as a new item with category 2. Which is exactly what they are showing in their example data.

Comment: @NigelRen and his code gives the result that *should be* :)) - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9ef72bfe8cc514e0783e3ffac05f455ca8732eb

Comment: @splash58, hence my first comment saying that I can't reproduce the problem.  But looks as though OP has just abandoned the question.

Comment: @splash58 that is the answar I except but the result is that the category of Array[0] change too . It seems theproblem  is not cause by code but the setting or other stuff... I even check the call by value/reference stuff but the problem still there .I'll keep finding the bug and sorry for the late reply , my time zone is utc+8 .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to achieve such a result:

```
$array_origin = array_reduce($array_origin, static function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[] = $item;

    if ($item['category'] === 1) {
        $item['category'] = 2;
        $carry[] = $item;
    }

    return $carry;
}, []);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/aJItn)

Answer (score 0):

You are using array_push() in your `foreach ($tempArr as $k => $v)`  section, that's why it adds up data into array_origin array. You should instead use loop and iterate value (as per your attempted logic)

```
    $tempArr=[];
    $array_origin =
    [
        0 =>[
            "id" => 1,
            "category"=>1
            ],

        1 =>[
            "id" => 2,
            "category"=>2
            ],
    ];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array_origin);


    foreach ($array_origin as $k => $v) 
    {
        if($v["category"] == 1)
        {
            array_push($tempArr,$v);
        }
    }

    echo 'TEMP';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($tempArr);


    foreach ($tempArr as $k => $v) 
    {
        if(array_key_exists($k, $array_origin)){
            $array_origin[$k]['id'] = $v['id'];
            $array_origin[$k]['category'] = $v['category'];
        }
    }


    print_r($array_origin);
```

Your output should now be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [category] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [category] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Doesn't your output show exactly the same as the input array?